# pass du (disk usage) result to a numeric variable

Tags: linux, hard-drive, shell-script, environment-variables, du

In a shell script, I'm looking for a way to pass the du (disk usage) result to a numeric variable, so that I cantie the execution of a shell script to the size of a specific folder. I've tried something like size=$(du -sh /folder) but this passes an alphanumeric value to the variable 'size', plus the name of the folder, which is obviously not what I want.

I'm using OSX, but I believe this is more of a bash/linux question. Has anybody an idea on how to achieve that? 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`size=$(du -s xxx | awk '{print $1}')` will give the disk usage in kB. To get real used bytes use `du -sb --apparent-size xxx`. See `man du` for details.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot Marki.